# calling the method 'count' returns wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby

I have a method which takes two parameters. An integer for (max_length) and a string for (text). If the amount of characters per word in the text is >= max_length we remove that word from the array. At the end we count the remaining words in the array.

My method works well until `text.count` where I encounter `'wrong number of arguments, given 0 expected 1+'`

I `know` this is because we haven't passed any arguments to `text.count` but I don't want to pass any in as I only want to count the remaining number of words left in the array.

However, if I performed a simple example of

```
x = ["This", "Will", "Work"]
x.count => 3
```

Why can't I use this example of count inside my block?

What am i doing wrong?

```
   def timed_reading(max_length, text)
     text.split.delete_if do |y|
       y.length >= max_length
       text.count
     end
   end
```

Comment: "What am i doing wrong?" - your count is in the block of `delete_if` and it should be outside.

Comment: The method name doesn't strike me as being particularly descriptive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you were trying to do

```
def timed_reading(max_length, text)
  text.split.delete_if { |y| y.length >= max_length }.count
end
```

You could just count words with length less than the max anyway

```
text.split.count { |y| y.length < max_length }
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to delete words if all you return is the count. You can simply use `count` with a block:

```
def timed_reading(max_length, text)
  text.split.count{|w| w.length < max_length}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `count` on the string `text` and not on the array. You need to rearrange your code so that you are calling count on the result of your `delete_if` call. Something like this:

```
def timed_reading(max_length, text)
  short_words = text.split.delete_if do |y| 
    y.length >= max_length
  end
  short_words.count
end
```